# localstorage and JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I need some help with figuring out how local storage and JSON works.

I have the following html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"> 
    <script src="Script.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
    <form name="test" method="post" action="javascript:storage()">
        <input name='surname' id="surname" value='surname'>
        <input name='lastname' id="lastname" value='lastname'>
        <input type="submit" value="test">
    </form>
    <div id="tabletest"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

the following javascript:

```
function storage(){
    var surname = document.getElementById('surname').value;
    var lastname = document.getElementById('lastname').value;
    var person = {
        "surname" : surname,
        "lastname" : lastname,
        "dateofbirth" : "01-01-1990"    
    };

    person = JSON.stringify(person);
    localStorage.setItem('person', person);

    var person2 = localStorage.getItem('person');
    var persons = JSON.parse(person);

    var tabletest = document.getElementById('tabletest');
    var person3 = JSON.parse(person2);
    tabletest.innerHTML += JSON.stringify(person3);
}
```

My problems/troubles:
The output I get in tabletest is this:

```
{ "surname":"surname", "lastname":"lastname", "geboortedatum":"01-01-1990" }
```

- How do I get only the surname and the lastname in the 'tabletest' div?
- How do I add a new value with the inputs from the textfields when the submitbutton is clicked (because push doesn't work)?

Comment: var person3 = JSON.parse(person2);
    tabletest.innerHTML += person3.surname + " " + person3.lastname

Comment: `tabletest.innerHTML += person3.surname + person3.lastname`;

Comment: push doesn't work because person is not array it is an object

Answer (score 0):

To get lastname(or I should say any value inside JSON) use

```
tabletest.innerHTML +="Lastname:"+person3.lastname+" Sirname:"+person3.sirname;
```

And to add to the JSON use:

```
person.newName = newName 
//or 
person["newName"] = newName;
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jasonwilczak/5dch55py/1/)

Right now, your logic shows you grabbing the value of first and last name, which is, currently: surname and lastname, respectively:

```
<input name='surname' id="surname" value='surname'>
 <input name='lastname' id="lastname" value='lastname'>
```

You need to run this function on the button click event and get the value and simply use the storage setItem(key,value) function. [Here is the documentation](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) .  You only need to stringify, then parse on the storage data.  After that, it is an object that you can get the properties from.

```
person = JSON.stringify(person);
    localStorage.setItem('person', person);

   var person2 = localStorage.getItem('person');
    var persons = JSON.parse(person2);

    var tabletest = document.getElementById('tabletest');
    tabletest.innerHTML += persons.surname + ' ' + persons.lastname;

You were very close on the logic, but you needed something like this:

    document.getElementById('btnTest').onclick = storage;
```

I also modified the 'submit' button to a standard 'button' element so that the form doesn't post:

```
 <button id='btnTest' value="test">Test</button>
```

You could then do Ajax.  Otherwise, you would need to do a [pre-submit function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19731265/before-form-submit-call-function-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Localstorage works on key-value pairs. Since you are using the same key, 'person', you are simply overwriting previous value. You could use an array of persons which you store using 'person' key but you are responsible for parsing/stringifying the array each time.

```
var personsStore = [];

function storage() {
   var s = localStorage.getItem("person");
   if (s) {
      personsStore = JSON.parse(s);
   }
   var person = {...} //after you get properties from dom input
   personsStore.push(person);
   var stringForm = JSON.stringify(personsStore");
   localStorage.setItem("person", stringForm);

  var tabletest = document.getElementById('tabletest');
  tabletest.innerHtml += stringForm;
}
```

If you want particular attributes the easiest way to do that is to use a tool like underscore (underscore.org). Appending to 'tabletest' becomes

```
  tabletest.innerHtml += JSON.stringify(_.map(personStore, fucntion(p) {
       return _.pick(p, "firstname", ....);
  });
```

Comment: Your code doesn't work.. the JSON.stringify has a " in it.. I removed it but it still doesn't show anything when I click..  I have put my person code into the var person { } .

Comment: :-) . Apologies. I quickly typed that and I assumed you'd get my logic therefore I didn't expect the fragment I wrote above to just work; Its just to guide you. The " in JSON.stringify(...) is a typo. Having _personsStore_ external variable is not necessary too.

Comment: Did you add the code: `tablest.innerHtml += JSON.stringify(...` ? If so did you include [link](underscore.org) ? There is a typo on  `function (p)...`. If nothing happens then could be a bug. Please check.