# Simulate User session with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, authentication

When a user visits below login screen and provides any user name and password, they should be considered a "logged in" user if they go to any subsequent pages without closing their browser.

```
<html>
<form action="" method="POST">
<span>Login:</span><input type="text" name="puname" ><br>
<span>Password:</span><input type="text" name="ppasswd"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Register"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone suggest how I can implement this with JavaScript (perhaps using cookies)?

Comment: You can use cookies or session storage: www.w3schools.com/Html/html5_webstorage.asp. but I think session storage works tab by tab

Comment: Are you using a server-side language? Take a look at sessions, or just a simple google search

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cookies are the way to go, you can then make the decision if you want them destroyed at browser close, or destroyed after set time(i.e. 1 day). If your not apposed to jquery, this plugin makes it very simple https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Comment: jquery is probably the easiest way to do this. The native JS methods aren't difficult to grasp though. Check out http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html The hardest part is the expiration, and in this case, for a prototype, if you don't set an expiration at all it'll delete when you close the browser.

Comment: How can I get the cookie to get created when they click the 'submit' button on the login form? Do I need to call the JS on the action of the form or the onclick of the submit button? Some examples would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to intercept the submit and run your set cookie. Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19731265/before-form-submit-call-function-javascript