# How to call servlet and do button action at the same time?

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, servlets

I'm using java+jsp/servlet+jquery making my webapp.

I have a button `<button id = "1">My button</button>` on my page, that should do 2 actions at the same time : `Servlet` call and some `jquery` script action like this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#1").click(function(){
            alert("Mouse click!");
        });
    });
</script>
```

How can I do this 2 things at the same time?

Comment: make an ajax call inside click handler also. Not clear what you want to send though

Comment: please refer to this answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/19731310/957654

Comment: on the above link in Amro's comment, don't use multipart when not uploading files. And here you clearly want ajax.

Comment: this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112686/how-to-use-servlets-and-ajax?rq=1 really helped me. Thank you all!